# no visible @interface eror in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't figure out why the problem described here is happening.

This my student.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Student : NSObject
@property NSString* fName;
@property NSString* lName;
@property NSString* studentId;
@property NSString* phoneNum;
@property NSString* degree;

-(id) init: (NSString*)fName lName:(NSString*)lName sId:(NSString*)sId pn:(NSString*)pn degree: (NSString*) degree;
@end
```

This is my student.m:

```
#import "Student.h"

@implementation Student

-(id) init: (NSString*)fName lName:(NSString*)lName sId:(NSString*)sId pn:(NSString*)pn degree: (NSString*) degree
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.fName = fName;
        self.lName = lName;
        self.studentId = sId;
        self.phoneNum = pn;
        self.degree = degree;
    }
    return self;

}

@end
```

And this is my main:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Student.h"
#import "StudentDB.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");


        Student* ignacio =[[Student alloc]  init: @"ignacio" lName: @"cooper" sId: @"123456" pn:@"01234"  degree:@"Computer science"];
        [[StudentDB instance] addStudents: ignacio];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is happening in this line:

```
Student* ignacio =[[Student alloc]  init: @"ignacio" lName: @"cooper" sId: @"123456" pn:@"01234"  degree:@"Computer science"];
```

Here's the entire error:

> no visible @interface for 'Student' declares the selector 'init:lName:sId:pn:degree'

Without the StudentDB it works fine.  It appears the trouble is there, but I can't find it. Can anyone give me an idea on how I can solve this?

Here are my StudentDB.h and StudentDB.m:

```
#import "StudentDB.h"

@implementation StudentDB
static StudentDB* instance = nil;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.students = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (StudentDB*) instance
{
    if(instance == nil){
        instance = [[StudentDB alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}

-(void) addStudents:(Student *)s
{
    [self.students addObject: s];
}

-(Student*) getStudent:(NSString*)sId
{
    for(Student* s in self.students)
    {
        if(s.studentId == sId)
            return s;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void) deleteStudent:(NSString*)sId
{

    for(Student* s in self.students)
    {
        if(s.studentId == sId){
            [self.students removeObject:s];
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void) updateStudent:(Student*)s
{
    [self deleteStudent: s.studentId];
    [self addStudents:s];
}

@end



#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Student.h"
@interface StudentDB : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray* students;

+(StudentDB*) instance;
-(id)init;
-(void) addStudents:(Student *)s;
-(Student*) getStudent:(NSString*)sId;
-(void) deleteStudent:(NSString*)sId;
-(void) updateStudent:(Student*)s;

@end
```

Comment: @0x7fffffff just did :)

Comment: Is the code in your question the actual, real code by using copy and paste and not by retyping?

Comment: FWIW, Objective-C is *so* much easier to read when you don't abbreviate parts of the method name. A better (more readable, at least) choice would have been something like: `-initWithFirstName:lastName:studentID:pin:degree:`.

Comment: Just checking because I don't the problem. The method name and what you are calling appear to be the same. But a tiny typo can make a huge difference.

Comment: Copy pasting that code in a new project, leaving out references to StudentDB work just fine, so either that's not the real code you are using, or something in StudentDB.h is interfering/redefining the Student class...

Comment: @FabioRitrovato i reedit the question with my StudentDB

Comment: Still working fine here :/